# double JOIN and GROUP on hasMany associations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 models (tables):

```
Presentation hasMany PresentationView hasMany SlideView
```

Fields:

Presentation: `id, title`

PresentationView: `id, presentation_id`

SlideView: `id, presentation_view_id, duration`

I need a query to get statistics for each presentation. Statistics are:

1. number of PresentationView per each Presentation
2. total duration of all SlideView.duration from slide views that belong to Presentation (through PresentationView)

So basically it seems like double JOIN and double GROUP but the joins doesn't work for me - I tried every combination of LEFT/INNER/RIGHT double joins and I can't make it work. The best I had it was that Presentation had grouped PresentationView but duration was SUMed just from SlideViews that belonged to just one PresentationViews not all for Presentation...

I would like to avoid nested SELECTs if possible. just JOIN/GROUP

Comment: It would help if you clarified what exactly and in what way didn't work for you. You could update your question with at least some of the combinations of joins you tried (actual queries). That might shed some light too on what you might have got wrong in your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is a simple JOIN and COUNT:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(*)
FROM Presentation p
JOIN PresentationView v ON p.id = v.presentation_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

The second one has to use a SUM (and JOIN):

```
SELECT p.id, SUM(s.duration)
FROM Presentation p
JOIN PresentationView v ON p.id = v.presentation_id
JOIN SlideView s ON v.id = s.presentation_view_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

If you want both in a single query:

```
SELECT p.id, SUM(s.duration), COUNT(DISTINCT v.id)
FROM Presentation p
JOIN PresentationView v ON p.id = v.presentation_id
JOIN SlideView s ON v.id = s.presentation_view_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

---

### Reason for `DISTINCT`:

Tables:

```
Presentation:    PresentationView:          SlideView:
p.id | title     v.id | presentation_id     s.id | presentation_view_id | duration
1    | abc       1    | 1                   1    | 1                    | 100
2    | xyz       2    | 1                   2    | 1                    | 150
                 3    | 1                   3    | 2                    | 200
                 4    | 1                   4    | 2                    | 250
                 5    | 1                   5    | 3                    | 300
                 6    | 2                   6    | 3                    | 400
                 7    | 2                   7    | 4                    | 500
                                            8    | 5                    | 600
                                            9    | 6                    | 100
                                            10   | 6                    | 200
                                            11   | 7                    | 350
```

Example result set BEFORE the group:

```
p.id | v.id | s.id | s.duration
-------------------------------
1    | 1    | 1    | 100
1    | 1    | 2    | 150
1    | 2    | 3    | 200
1    | 2    | 4    | 250
1    | 3    | 5    | 300
1    | 3    | 6    | 400
1    | 4    | 7    | 500
1    | 5    | 8    | 600
2    | 6    | 9    | 100
2    | 6    | 10   | 200
2    | 7    | 11   | 350
```

AFTER the group without distinct:

```
p.id | SUM | COUNT
------------------
1    | 8   | 2500
2    | 3   | 650
```

With distinct:

```
p.id | SUM | COUNT
------------------
1    | 5   | 2500
2    | 2   | 650
```

Comment: Hey - your answer is good but you are missing `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT` -> see my answer

Answer (score 0):

In mean time I found answer:

```
SELECT presentations.title, SUM(slide_views.duration), COUNT(DISTINCT presentation_views.id) 
FROM presentations 
LEFT JOIN presentation_views ON presentations.id = presentation_views.presentation_id 
LEFT JOIN slide_views ON presentation_views.id = slide_views.presentation_view_id 
GROUP BY presentations.id
```

Comment: this `DISTINCT` is senseless, because id is the primary key and has to be distinct by nature. .. or maybe .. let me think about it

Comment: Now I'm sure about it :D You are right. But only if you join all three tables! example: 1 presentation has 4 views, those 4 views have each 2 slides. So after `group by presentation.id` there will be each `presentation_view.id` TWO times.